# My Project doesn't have spatial mapping renderer component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have hololens2 and I wanna implement spatial mapping renderer component. However, my project doesn't have it. My unity version 2020.3.33f1. What should I fix or update to have it.

Answer (score 0):

In Unity 2020.3.33f1, you should use MRTK to implement Spatial Mapping instead of the spatial mapping renderer component, which is used in Legacy WSA. For more information, please refer to [Spatial mapping in Unity - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-mapping-in-unity?tabs=mrtk#how-to-add-mapping-in-unity).

Comment: I have already MRTK features in project. You mean enabling Spatial Awereness? but even with that there is nothing Spatial Mapping, am I correct? Spatial Mapping has been replaced by Spatial Awereness?

Comment: Spatial Awareness is a feature used to implement Spatial Mapping in MRTK. If you want to use Spatial Awareness, you can refer to [Spatial awareness getting started - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/spatial-awareness/spatial-awareness-getting-started?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) to configure the Profile or use the default Profile, you can also try **Demos-SpatialAwareness** in the MRTK Examples package.